# Header and div appear on the same line

Tags: html, css

So I have my header with a background image set and I want to create a div underneath it so I can write text there, but when I create the new div, the text I write inside of it appears on top of the already created header. I think it is due to the background image I have set. This is one of my first projects made all by my own so if you guys could help me it will be really appreciated.

These are the HTML and CSS files:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color:#f4f4f4;
 float: left;
}

header{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.3);
 margin: auto;
}


.wtf {
 padding-right: 50px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 3px;
}

#logo {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
 padding-left: 20px;
}


p.highlight {
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 7px;
}


ul {
 float:right;
}

li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 21px;
 margin: 0 0 3px 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.image {
 background-image: url('nebula-stars-universe-galaxy-space-4k-kx-1920x1080.jpg');
}

.main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 color: white;
 text-align: justify;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 background-image: url('nebula-stars-universe-galaxy-space-4k-kx-1920x1080.jpg')
}

.main p,h1,h3 {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.main h1 {
 top: 100px;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.main h3 {
 top: 120px;
}

.main p {
 top: 90px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.development {
 position: relative;
}

.development p {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Упражнение</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Concert+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-+0VIRx+yz1WBc


</head>
<body>

<header>
 <div class="image">
     <nav>
      <div id="logo">
      <h1><p class="highlight">ATANAS DEVELOPING</p></h1>
     </div>
     
     <div class="wtf">
     <ul> 
      <li class="current">
       <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Clients</a>
      </li>
      <li>
    <a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
 
 <div class="main">
  <p>Can you build the website of my dreams?</p>
  <h1>YUP, WE CAN DO THAT.</h1>
  <h3>Learn More</h3>
 </div>
 </div>
</header>
 
 <br>
 <div class="development">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam lacus quis ex malesuada fermentum. Sed fringilla porttitor massa sit amet sollicitudin.</p>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _(sidenote)_ There are also other issues in your markup. Checkout [https://validator.w3.org/](https://validator.w3.org/). This site will help you to find errors and also suggest best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You positioned your `.main` absolutely:

```
.main {
    position: absolute;
}
```

With this styling you take `.main` out of the normal document flow and it is positioned in the top left corner. The other elements stay in regular flow and are right above it. Just get rid of this positioning and you are good to go.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color:#f4f4f4;
 float: left;
}

header{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: auto;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: rgba(192,192,192,0.3);
 margin: auto;
}


.wtf {
 padding-right: 50px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 3px;
}

#logo {
 float: left;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
 padding-left: 20px;
}


p.highlight {
 margin: 0;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 7px;
}


ul {
 float:right;
}

li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 21px;
 margin: 0 0 3px 0;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.image {
 background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=15');
}

.main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 color: white;
 text-align: justify;
 /* position: absolute; <-- do not position this absolutely */
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080?image=10')
}

.main p,h1,h3 {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.main h1 {
 top: 100px;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.main h3 {
 top: 120px;
}

.main p {
 top: 90px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.development {
 position: relative;
}

.development p {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Concert+One" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/solid.css" >


 <div class="image">
     <nav>
      <div id="logo">
      <h1><p class="highlight">ATANAS DEVELOPING</p></h1>
     </div>
     
     <div class="wtf">
     <ul> 
      <li class="current">
       <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Clients</a>
      </li>
      <li>
    <a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
 
 <div class="main">
  <p>Can you build the website of my dreams?</p>
  <h1>YUP, WE CAN DO THAT.</h1>
  <h3>Learn More</h3>
 </div>
  
 </div>

 
 <div class="development">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi aliquam lacus quis ex malesuada fermentum. Sed fringilla porttitor massa sit amet sollicitudin.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your .main css class has an absolute position. Disabling that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove some `position` property from your css.

```
.development {
    // remove
    //position: relative;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
   // remove 
   // position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-image: url(nebula-stars-universe-galaxy-space-4k-kx-1920x1080.jpg);
}
```

Changing to above would work but your `body` is floated towards left so remove that too.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
   // remove
   // float: left;
}
```